# Include Javascript Variable In HTML in Javascript

Tags: jquery, html, hyperlink, onclick, append

I am using jquery to append content to my html. In the onclick function, I want to send a javascript variable to a function but it is not working.

Here is the code:

```
var link = "some url";
$('#header').append('<a onclick="activateLink(link);">Click</a>');

function activateLink(vlink)
{
    window.open(vlink, '_blank');
}
```

I have tried the following

```
$('#header').append('<a onclick="activeLink**("'+link+'")**;">Click</a>');
```

AND

```
$('#header').append('<a onclick="activeLink**('+link+')**;">Click</a>');
```

nothing seems to work. any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is `link` a local variable? Inline Javascript can only access global variables.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest:

```
$('<a />', {
    'text' : 'Click',
    'click' : function(){
        activateLink(link);
     }
}).appendTo('#header');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/nBJCC/).